# Do I have to uinstall MariaDB to give way to another open-source database?

Tags: mongodb, mariadb

I am planning to install MongoDB because it's one requirement for a job, but currently I have MariaDB installed on my PC. Is is safe to install mongoDB if I still have the MariaDB installed? Or do I  have to uninstall MariaDB first? need help before making a move. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They won't interact, it's like having Firefox and Chrome both installed at once.

Also, [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/) is a SQL-based database while [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is a NoSQL database (so you're going to have to learn how Mongo handles input, etc).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem at all. You can even have multiple MongoDBs installed at the same server. Just download and install it, and it will work fine. Good luck with MongoDB!